# How can I fire "MouseEnter" of a control when I do "MouseEnter" to another?

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I have a `panel` and inside this `panel` I have a `label`. What I want to do is to fire `panel`'s `MouseEnter` but when I do `MouseEnter` on `label` control. Any idea?

Comment: What should happen after panel's MousEnter event? What do you want to do? Please share your code.

Comment: I don't have any code for this yet... When user moves over this panel, it does some stuff like change it's back color, it's border color etc. And inside this panel I added a label. So when user moves over label, as is to be expected, panel doesn't act like when user moved over panel. And this is what I want to do. To make panel looks like someone moved over it even when user moves over label.

Answer (score 1):

When `MouseEnter` event of your panel is fired all handlers that are subscribed to this event will be called. So, instead of firing panel's event you can call those handlers. See following demo code.

```
Color backColor;

private void Panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backColor = panel1.BackColor;
    panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}

private void Panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.BackColor = backColor;
}

private void Label1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel1_MouseEnter(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private void Label1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel1_MouseLeave(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Comment: There is no `private void Panel1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)` and `private void Panel1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)` into my code. This panel is a third party control.

Comment: These are handler methods and you are supposed to subscribe them to events of your panel and label.

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
private void label_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel.RaiseEvent(new MouseEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0) { RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseEnterEvent });
}
```